# How do I program this Dijkstra shortest distance algorithm in R?

Tags: r, igraph, dijkstra

Here is my Dijkstra data matrix. Note: distances between two nodes i and j that are not directly linked have been set to NA.

```
     node X1 X2 X3 X4 X5 X6
[1,]    1  0  3  7  4 NA NA
[2,]    2  3  0  2 NA NA  9
[3,]    3  7  2  0  1  3  6
[4,]    4  4 NA  1  0  3 NA
[5,]    5 NA NA  3  3  0  3
[6,]    6 NA  9  6 NA  3  0
```

I need to write a code that provide the shortest distance from Node 1 to Node N (so only a single number output is required, not the shortest path). 
The program should also work on a csv-file holding a symmetrical square direct-distance matrix of any dimensions, with any number of nodes numbered 1···N, and any positive distance values in the matrix. (Your program will be tested on such matrix.) The program should output the shortest distance from Node 1 to Node N.

I tried:
Creating Temporary Matrix L(0)

```
l0data<-c(1,MatrixData[[1,1]],"Temp",2,MatrixData[[1,2]],"Temp",3,MatrixData[[1,3]],"Temp",4 ,MatrixData[[1,4]],"Temp",5, MatrixData[[1,5]],"Temp",6, MatrixData[[1,6]],"Temp")
l0<-matrix(l0data,nrow = 3, ncol = 6)
temp0<-l0[3,]=="Temp"
```

Select values & Node of L(0) to make permanent

```
l0SelectVal<-l0[2,temp0]
#select nodes of temporary l0
l0SelectNod<-l0[1,temp0]
```

Answers mininimum value of L(0)

```
L0<-which.min(l0SelectVal)
L0#value not used = step in between
L0Nod<-l0SelectNod[L0]
L0Val<-l0SelectVal[which.min(l0SelectVal)]
```

Then I repeated this for 6x times for L(1),...L(5) and:

Output shortest distance Matrix

```
AllData<-c("Node","Distance",L0Nod,L0Val,L1Nod,L1Val,L2Nod,L2Val,L3Nod,L3Val,L4Nod,L4Val,L5Nod,L5Val)
outputdata<-matrix(AllData,nrow = 2, ncol = 7)
outputdata[,c(4,5)]<-outputdata[,c(5,4)]
```

But obviously this is not the smartest way. So, help please: How do I write this code more efficiently?

Comment: Updated post with things I've tried. 
Would be nice if Andrew & co. could refrain judgements; because I've tried before asking but very new and not gifted at this. Thank you!

Comment: Perhaps you could use the `igraph` package. First use `graph.adjacency` with `weighted` argument on your matrix (but set `NA` to `0`, then `shortest.paths` (select what `algorithm` you want). `shortest.paths` calculates the shortest distance http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/igraph/docs/average.path.length

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Upgrade comment - I think you could use the functions in the `igraph` package for this

```
library(igraph)

# your data
mat <- as.matrix(read.table(text=
"node X1 X2 X3 X4 X5 X6
   1  0  3  7  4 NA NA
    2  3  0  2 NA NA  9
    3  7  2  0  1  3  6
    4  4 NA  1  0  3 NA
    5 NA NA  3  3  0  3
    6 NA  9  6 NA  3  0", header=T))

# prepare data for graph functions - set NA to zero to indicate no direct edge
nms <- mat[,1]
mat <- mat[, -1]
colnames(mat) <- rownames(mat) <- nms
mat[is.na(mat)] <- 0


# create graph from adjacency matrix
g <- graph.adjacency(mat, weighted=TRUE)
#plot(g)

# Get all path distances
(s.paths <- shortest.paths(g, algorithm = "dijkstra"))
#   1 2 3 4 5  6
#1  0 3 5 4 7 10
#2  3 0 2 3 5  8
#3  5 2 0 1 3  6
#4  4 3 1 0 3  6
#5  7 5 3 3 0  3
#6 10 8 6 6 3  0
```

Comment: Sorry. I didn't understand the solution. So what is the computed shortest path from the result ?

Comment: @ZeroGraviti ; sorry not been on site. The final matrix gives the shortest paths between each node . ie. between nodes 1 & 2 is 3, nodes 1 & 3 is 5 etc (note the distance matrix is symmetric)